# Android Studio Login Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm working at my first app and I want to login to a php website, but  want to use the Login Activity of Android Studio. My design looks perfect but I don't know how I can access my Database. So how can I compare the email entered from the user and the email saved in the databse?...same for the password.
Thanks a lot for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Your app doesn't know your webpage's database. You need to do add some backend API to your website (via REST, SOAP, HTTP or whatever) so that the app can query for users with given name/password and make that api call from the app. I strongly recommend using encryption.

Comment: okay...but what do I have to integrate in my Android project that the Login Activity knows which website or database to pick, etc.?